# Angular Material 2 MdMenu as a main navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create main navigation in my Angular application using MdMenu component from Angular Material 2.

One of the main issues is double click which is needed to open another one menu (we first need to close oppened menu and then open another menu).

Does anyone have any example how to solve this problem?

Comment: For navigation in Material, MdToolbarRow is used. MdMenu is usually for options.

Comment: I need drop-down menu and I don't know how it should looks using MdToolbarRow.